scrape a dropdown list using playwright
I'm struggling to find a way to click on the "All" option in a dropdown list and scrape all the content inside that page. I have come across a few posts but they're a little different from my situation. My "select" seems to not have id or label, with an empty "name".
The website I'm scraping is https://www.nba.com/stats/players/traditional?Season=1998-99&SeasonType=Regular+Season
<div class="Pagination_pageDropdown__KgjBU">
 <div class="DropDown_content__Bsm3h">
  <label class="DropDown_label__lttfI">
   <p data-no-label="true"></p>
  <div class="DropDown_dropdown__TMlAR">
   <select name="" class="DropDown_select__4pIg9">
     <option value="-1">All</option>
     <option value="0">1</option>
     <option value="1">2</option>
     <option value="2">3</option
     <option value="3">4</option>
     <option value="4">5</option>
     <option value="5">6</option>
     <option value="6">7</option>
     <option value="7">8</option>
     <option value="8">9</option>
   </select>

...
My current code looks like this:
import asyncio
from playwright.async_api import async_playwright
from NBA.spiders.nba import NbaScraping
`async def main():
    async with async_playwright() as p:
        browser = await p.chromium.launch(headless=False)
        page = await browser.new_page()
        spider = NbaScraping()
        spider.start_requests()
        for url in spider.start_urls:
            await page.goto(url)
            selector =  page.locator('.Pagination_pageDropdown__KgjBU.DropDown_select__4pIg9')
            await selector.wait_for()
            page.select_option(value='-1')
            page.wait_for_timeout(5999)
        await browser.close()

asyncio.run(main())`

I expect to scrape all the content from the "All" option in the dropdown list. I have spent a week on such problem but I couldn't find a solution that works. I'm still new to this so forgive me if the question sounds naive to most of you

Your problem is the selector. page.locator('.Pagination_pageDropdown__KgjBU.DropDown_select__4pIg9') is trying to select an element that has both classes, .Pagination_pageDropdown__KgjBU and .DropDown_select__4pIg9, which isn't what you want - you're trying to select only the select tag.
Try page.locator('.DropDown_select__4pIg9'). I'd bet that solves your problem.
See Select element based on multiple classes or CSS selectors reference for an explanation.
